# Brake pads dragging on front discs on Honda CBR125R (2012)

Tags: motorcycle, brakes

For the past couple months I noticed that my bike has been feeling a little less energetic and slowly I began to notice that it was because my front brake was still touching my discs & it was confirmed to me when I started to hear a grinding noise from the front of my bike all the time.

I've opened the brakes, pushed the pads back and taken away from the brake fluid because I thought I had too much fluid. Didn't work.
At the moment I have so little fluid that my front brake is pretty much useless, it's the only way I can ride the bike without it randomly beginning to slow down because the brake decided to clench.

I have no idea what else could be the reason, the pads are also brand new btw.

Answer (score 2):

The brake caliper should retract just a little bit once you've used them. It isn't doing this, so more than likely your caliper either needs a rebuild or it needs to be replaced.

There is a piston seal within the caliper which sits at an angle. The seal becomes straight when you apply the brakes. When you release the brakes, the seal becomes straight again. When it does, it takes the caliper piston with it, pulling it away from the rotor and taking the pressure off of the pad. It seems yours isn't doing this so the piston is keeping pressure up on the pads causing them to rub on the rotor all the time.

Comment: Is there any way to diagnose which is the cause, because I don't have much money to test all the possibilities so I was hoping there'd be a way to pinpoint the cause?

Comment: Which is what cause? I'm pretty sure your caliper is bad. If you are asking about rebuild vs. replace, that's up to you and your pocketbook.